# Clearing input field text after button click

Tags: javascript

Am trying to get the value from input and display it, once I input another value, the previous value is still returned,once I click the add button but I dont want it to. How can I solve this is Javascript
here is my code.

```js
const addEvent = document.querySelector('.add');
const eventUserInput = document.querySelector('.input2');
const parentEl = document.querySelector('.event-list');

eventUserInput.addEventListener('keyup', (user_input)=>{
    let userValue = user_input.target.value;
    // console.log(userValue);
    addEvent.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        const storeElement = document.createElement('p');
        const storeElementText = storeElement.innerHTML = userValue;
        console.log(storeElement);
        parentEl.appendChild(storeElement);
        eventUserInput.value = '';
        // document.getElementById('input').value = '';
        // parentEl.push(storeElement)

    })
})
```

```html
 <div class="list">
        <label for="input"></label>
        <input type="text" id="input" class="input2" placeholder="enter activity">
        <i class="ri-add-fill add">btn</i>

        <div class="event-list">
        
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you really want to register an event listener every time a key was pressed?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. You have a keyup listener and a click listener. What should happen in each case? It doesn't seem like there's any point to the keyup handler. It just sets a variable, but the click listener can do that itself.

Comment: Well I think I had mistaken, just as you have said, I dont want the event to be triggered once I keyup, thats where I was going wrong, thank you